# R: rank objects in a vector - don't skip an integer after a tie

Tags: r

This seems like a simple question but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Given the following vector:

```
a <- c(1, 6, 6, 11)
```

How do I output a corresponding vector of value ranks like the one below

```
1 2 2 3
```

In other words, is there a way to use the `rank()` or something similar that identifies ties, but doesn't skip an integer on the subsequent value rank.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dense_rank`

```
library(dplyr)
dense_rank(a)
#[1] 1 2 2 3
```

---

Or with `frank`

```
library(data.table)
frank(a, ties.method = 'dense')
#[1] 1 2 2 3
```

---

Or in `base R` with `match`

```
match(a, unique(a))
#[1] 1 2 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks. In looking into the function you mentioned. I also found the relatively simple solution below for people who are trying to stick with base R that seems to work. `match(a, sort(unique(a)))`

Comment: @nbsullivan742 you can use `match` from `base R`.   I thought you specifically want the `rank` function

Comment: I was trying to figure out something with `rank()`, but honestly, whatever gets the job done. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also treat the vector `a` as factor and the transform to numeric like this:

```
#Code
as.numeric(as.factor(a))
```

Output:

```
[1] 1 2 2 3
```